# Change a single value of a subdocument in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a Model called `Notes`. It has a subdocument `requests` which holds various documents with values `userId`, `reqType`, `accepted` value( `false` by default) and `noteId` of the sender, request and note respectively. When the user hits a certain route I want to keep all the data to be as their previous values, just updating the `accepted` field to `true`.

The below code leads to no change in the data or a different iteration leads to erasing all the data other than `accepted` field and modifying it to `true`.

How should I do this?

```
const noteSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    requests: [
      {
        userId: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
        noteId: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
        reqType: String,
        accepted: {
          type: Boolean,
          default: false,
        },
      },
    ],
  }
)

const Note = mongoose.model('Note', noteSchema)

const note = await Note.findById(req.body.noteId)

await note.updateOne({
      requests: {
        $elemMatch: {
          userId: req.body.userId,
          reqType: req.body.reqType,
          noteId: req.body.noteId,
        },
        $set: { "requests.$.accepted": true },
      }, 
    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to retrieve the document and then update it. Just update it. Use this one:

```
await Note.updateOne(
    {
        "requests.userId": req.body.userId,
        "requests.reqType": req.body.reqType,
        "requests.noteId": req.body.noteId
    },
    {
        $set:
        {
           "requests.$.accepted":true
        }
    }
);
```

I checked, it worked.

With first part mongoose will find the document, with `$set` it will be updated.

Comment: The requests field is an array of objects. There is nothing as requests.userId. I got this error:`Cannot create field 'noteId' in element {requests: [ { accepted: false, _id: ObjectId('5e9c182a13a35c45f813964d'), userId: ObjectId('5e451b091e6d286b04f19a4f'), reqType: "edit", noteId: ObjectId('5e9b6fb478d0f94210c7a265') } ]}`

Comment: I checked it a lot and worked. May I see your query that gave you this error? When you enter ```requests.userId, ...``` and requests is an array, it searches and find the element in the array that matches this condition. Then in ```$set``` part, with ```$``` you'll have the index of element in array. So you can edit it.

Comment: Hey man, thanks it worked! Rechecked my query and I was using `note` in place of `Note`. Any idea how I can do it with a selected document `note` which I've already queried for with` findById`? Since I'm using that document to modify it elsewhere in the file as well.

Comment: Very well. You should first find the array element and then set it to true, after that ```await note.save()```. ```note.requests[note.requests.indexOf(<your object>)].accepted = true; await note.save();```